# Difference between the claims in Azure AD tokens between localhost and App Service

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, token

I'm developing a Blazor Server App intended for internal org use. That includes Azure tenant with Azure AD, app hosted on Azure App Services, app registrations... I'd say nothing extraordinary.

I'm getting the identity tokens from Azure ID for authentication & authorization.

In the App Registration under `Manage->Token configuration` I added optional claims for `family_name` and `given_name`.

I can read them when testing on localhost using code such as this:

```
user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName)?.Value;
// ClaimTypes.GivenName is shorthand for:
// "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname"
```

When deployed on Azure App Service this code returns `null`. The expected value has to be accessed with:

```
user.FindFirst("given_name")?.Value;
```

Which doesn't work on localhost...

I also noticed that there are further differences between the claim names and even between the number of claims.

I would expect the same names for the Claims identifiers and don't understand why is there a difference at all.

Can someone please elaborate?

Thanks

`Edit:`

I get the token with everything allright, but when listing the `key, value` pairs in `user.Claims` I get this:

```
localhost:
(key: value)
[...]
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname": "Marty",
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role": "Admin",
[...]

App Service:
[...]
"given_name": "Marty",
"roles": "Admin",
[...]
```

Basically all ClaimTypes that are defined in the C# class `ClaimTypes.[...]` and use the long `hhtp://schemas.microsoft...` format are replaced with shorter names when deployed, whereas the localhost app gets them with the longer names.

Comment: What does `user` have in it in the failng case? Is the user `user` object empty or missing properties?

Comment: they are "the same" (to a certain degree), it's just the `key` parts of many if not all Claims are different

Comment: So it seems App Service is return a claim type that doens't have the correct value for a key. Perhaps there is a library version mismatch between the App Service and your local build as per here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70456703/1690193

Comment: I don't see it as applicable; the library mentioned there is currently several versions higher. I deployed the application as `self-contained` (was previously `framework-dependent`) and nothing changed. What I did notice after reading the item you mentioned: when listing the claims I see one with `"ver":"2.0"` on the deployed app, but nothing equivalent on localhost.

Comment: Basically what I learnt from my reading is that 1. The schema that it returns seems partially dependent on local libraries; 2. There is also some kind a schema transformation layer. Either of thes things might be contributing to the different schema that you are seeing.

Comment: Yeah, this schema transformation layer is something I could explore. To your point 1: this should be mitigated when deploying the app as `self-contained` (i.e. framework and all dependencies are bundled with the app - afaik). On the other hand, the claims list is not identical: `count` is different and even some values with identical keys e.g. `aid` (app id I assume) are different. To me it seems there's some other thing in play.

Comment: I wonder if it would help / be possible to capture the JWT in the console and decode it here, to see what kind of schema is sent back from the identity provider. This might shed some light on where the schema is changing.  https://jwt.io/

Answer (score 0):

The differences you are observing in the claim names between localhost and Azure App Service are likely due to the way token claims are serialized and handled by the underlying authentication libraries in different environments.

When you run your Blazor Server App locally (localhost), you might be using the full claim type names (e.g., `"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname"`) because that's the default behavior or configuration for the development environment.

However, when your app is deployed to Azure App Service, the token claims may be normalized to a more concise format, such as `"given_name"`. This normalization is common to improve token compactness and reduce redundancy during transmission.

To ensure consistency in your code, you can use constants or well-known strings for claim types, regardless of whether your app is running locally or in the Azure App Service environment.

For example:

```
// Define constants for claim types
public static class CustomClaimTypes
{
    public const string GivenName = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname";
    public const string Role = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role";
}

// Usage
var givenName = user.FindFirst(CustomClaimTypes.GivenName)?.Value;
var role = user.FindFirst(CustomClaimTypes.Role)?.Value;
```

This way, your code remains consistent across environments, and you can handle claim types using the constants you've defined, regardless of whether the claim types are presented in the full format or the shortened format.

In summary, the differences you are seeing are likely related to the normalization of claim names, and using constants or well-known strings for claim types in your code can help maintain consistency across environments.

You can refer MSDocs

[System.Security.Claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims?view=net-8.0)

[Claims-Aware Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb736227%28v=vs.85%29)

Comment: it would be great if you could specify how to get the same behavior in both environments; also your suggestion with the static class is not applicable because the string keys (i.e. parameter for `FindFirst`) are different in those environments and won't return/find the value in each situation; also your `CustomClaimTypes` is mostly already implemented in `ClaimTypes` class (and I was using it already)